# Automatically open Jira ticket for issues in Snyk

Tags: security, jira, snyk

I would like to be able to open tickets automatically from Snyk to Jira for new issues found. Based on new or existing vulnerabilities.

And I would like to be able to create Jira tickets for issues already in the code.

Looked at [Snyk APIs](https://snyk.docs.apiary.io/#reference/projects/project-jira-issues/create-jira-issue) and looked at the UI way of opening ticket but it is not scalable. We want to automate this task and have it automated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a tool called ***[jira-tickets-for-new-vulns](https://docs.snyk.io/snyk-api-info/other-tools/tool-jira-tickets-for-new-vulns)***, it provides the means to sync your Snyk-monitored projects and automatically open Jira tickets for new issues and existing issue(s) without ticket(s) already created.

Cron it every X minutes/hours and fix the issues. This tool is aimed to be executed at regular intervals or with a trigger of your choice (webhooks). It can be could like this:

```
./snyk-jira-sync-<yourplatform> 
    -orgID=<SNYK_ORG_ID>                    // Can find it under settings
    -token=<API Token>                      // Snyk API Token. Service accounts work.
    -jiraProjectKey=<Key>                   // Jira project Key the tickets will be opened against 
    --severity=critical                     // optional: critical|high|medium|low
```

You can also find some extended options to set this up, for example apply this just for 'High' severity vulnerabilities and above.